Create labelled column from numeric and character columns
Having two columns, one with numeric values and other with text labels that correspond exactly with the numeric values, how can I create a labelled column (<dbl+lbl>), like the ones imported by the {haven} package?
Example data:
structure(list(cut_comuna = c("16303", "8301", "13111", "13201", 
                              "1101", "8110", "14204", "6101"), 
               comuna = c("Ñiquén", "Los Angeles", 
                          "La Granja", "Puente Alto", "Iquique", "Talcahuano", "Río Bueno", 
                          "Rancagua")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -8L),
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  cut_comuna comuna     
  <chr>      <chr>      
1 16303      Ñiquén     
2 8301       Los Angeles
3 13111      La Granja  
4 13201      Puente Alto
5 1101       Iquique    
6 8110       Talcahuano 
7 14204      Río Bueno  
8 6101       Rancagua   

Expected result, something like this:
  comuna2                                             
  <dbl+lbl>                                          
1 16303 [Ñiquén] 
2 8301  [Los Angeles]                              
...


As an alternative you can create a named vector with no data loss.
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(comuna2 = `names<-`(cut_comuna, comuna))

df$comuna2
     Ñiquén Los Angeles   La Granja Puente Alto     Iquique  Talcahuano
    "16303"      "8301"     "13111"     "13201"      "1101"      "8110"
  Río Bueno    Rancagua
    "14204"      "6101"


There is no dbl+lbl class but you can create a character variable combining two columns.
library(tidyverse)

df = structure(list(cut_comuna = c("16303", "8301", "13111", "13201", 
                                   "1101", "8110", "14204", "6101"), 
                    comuna = c("Ñiquén", "Los Angeles", 
                               "La Granja", "Puente Alto", "Iquique", "Talcahuano", "Río Bueno", 
                               "Rancagua")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -8L),
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% transmute(comuna2 = glue::glue("{cut_comuna} [{comuna}]"))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 1
#>   comuna2            
#>   <glue>             
#> 1 16303 [Ñiquén]     
#> 2 8301 [Los Angeles] 
#> 3 13111 [La Granja]  
#> 4 13201 [Puente Alto]
#> 5 1101 [Iquique]     
#> 6 8110 [Talcahuano]  
#> 7 14204 [Río Bueno]  
#> 8 6101 [Rancagua]

Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.0.2
If you want to keep the original columns use mutate instead of transmute.
Note that your cut_comuna variable is not numeric, but character. Anyway, it does not affect the results.
